# Play! and model validation

Tags: playframework

I have been using play 1.2.5rc4 for development of one app and I have found an interesting behaviour of Play. Look at the following code:

```
User user = new User(some attributes...);
boolean userSaved = user.validateAndSave();
```

During the call to new User I add a validation error using validation.addError() method. Then I would expect that during the validateAndSave() it returns false, as the validation already contains an error. But it doesn't. I am wondering whether this is a bug, or feature. I mean, can anyone think of some use case when this behaviour would be useful?

Another question is, why is validateAndSave() not the default save() method? I would expect that if I call user.save() it wouldn't save a user which violates the constraints, but apparently it does (I have an example, where a user violating the @Unique constraint gets inserted into db). Any idea why this can be useful? Wouldn't it be better to have method save() behaving as validateAndSave() and then a method e.g. saveWithoutValidation()? I can see the current naming of the methods causing a lot of problems.

Comment: Please fix the above code. You have there "User.validateAndSave()", but it probably should be "user.validateAndSave()"... just to have it right here on stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate and save does not look at the existing validation object, but instead validates the specific object that you are asking to be validated.

Your second question is because you may have some validation, which is specific to one of your screen designs, but maybe on an admin screen, you want to have different business rules. Forcing objects to be correct at all times is a restriction to the developer that should not be forced by the framework.

Comment: Yes, that's what I noticed. Is there any way to make it consider previous errors as well, other than checking validation.hasErrors?

Comment: And I am not sure I understand why would you want to have a validation of a model change depending on whether you are at admin screen or normal screen. Surely if you set up constraints about your data, you would like to adhere to them everywhere. And it would not be forcing, you would still have saveWithoutValidation, I just think whenever you are saving a model, you probably want it to be valid. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm always glad to learn something new.

Comment: I think it is a matter of personal preference, and the developers did not want to enforce a particular style.

Comment: Well, I see, but by not enforcing this style, they kind of enforced the other style, where you have to validate explicitly. I just think it may save people troubles if the validation was done inside save() and not validating would have to be called explicitly. E.g. the uniqeness is not validated when you call save(), then your underlying database will complain, that the entry can't be saved. 
Alternatively, maybe it should be advertised more that save() doesn't do the validation, 'cos I was pretty surprised when I found out.

Comment: And could you please explain, why you think it is useful to have different model validations for different screens? Surely they can have different validations in the Controller, but why in the model? Can you give some example please?

Comment: Well this is the thing. The Model class validations are sent back to the screen, so screen and model validations are linked.

Comment: Yes, but isn't the point of the Model validations that all the data that are stored must conform to them, regardless of what screen they come from?